# Django REST framework HyperlinkedIdentityField format kwarg not working

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have just started looking into Django REST Framework and am following the [tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/) in the official documentation. In this tutorial, we use `HyperLinkedIdentityField` for `highlight` attribute. We set the `format` kwarg to `html`.
The tutorial states:

> Notice that we've also added a new 'highlight' field. This field is of the same type as the url field, except that it points to the 'snippet-highlight' url pattern, instead of the 'snippet-detail' url pattern.
>
> Because we've included format suffixed URLs such as '.json', we also
> need to indicate on the highlight field that any format suffixed
> hyperlinks it returns should use the '.html' suffix.

The problem is that when I visit the snippet-list using the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/?format=json` I get the highlight url as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/1/highlight/?format=json` while I expected it to be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/1/highlight/?format=html` because no matter what format we request the `snippet-list` url, the `highlight` link will always have HTML format.
My code looks like this:

```
highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='snippet-highlight', format='html')


class Meta:
    model = Snippet
    fields = ['url', 'id', 'highlight', 'owner',
              'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style']
```

Any help will be highly appreciated
Thanks,